# How to handle generic type parameters for this lambda function function: Type not within bound error

Tags: java, generics, selenium, enums

I have a top-level `Link class` which extends `SlowLoadableComponent` in the Selenium support library.

This `class` is meant to be instantiated directly as well as to be extended by `class`es which provide more specialized behavior for `Link`s which lead to specific types of resources. Meanwhile, I have a generified lambda function which is supposed to take a `WebElement`, `Link class` and provide an instance of the specified `Link class`. I am having some difficulty designing the infrastructure in a way that doesn't result in a complaint from the compiler that my type parameter is not within its bounds when I try to create an instance of the lambda function to pass to the constructor for another class.

The `Link class` (reduced to minimal code):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.LoadableComponent;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.SlowLoadableComponent;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.SystemClock;

public class Link<T extends LoadableComponent<T>> extends SlowLoadableComponent<T> {

    private final WebElement link;
    private final WebDriver driver;

    public Link(final WebDriver driver, final WebElement link, final int timeoutInSeconds) {
        super(new SystemClock(), timeoutInSeconds);

        this.link = link;
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @Override
    protected void load() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void isLoaded() throws Error {

        try {
            assertTrue(link.isDisplayed());
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The lambda function:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class GetLinkFunction<L extends Link> implements Function<WebElement,L> {

    private final WebDriver driver;
    private final Class<? extends L> linkClass;

    public GetLinkFunction(WebDriver driver, Class<? extends L> linkClass) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.linkClass = linkClass;
    }

    public final L apply(WebElement element)
    {
        try {
            Constructor<? extends L> linkConstructor = linkClass.getConstructor(WebDriver.class, WebElement.class);
            return (linkClass.cast(linkConstructor.newInstance(driver, element)));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Failed to construct an instance of link class " + linkClass.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the invocation of the constructor for the Lambda function:

```
//This line causes the error-- the compiler complains that the type parameter Link is not within its bounds and should extend Link. I was under the impression that a type parameter like 'L extends Link' should accept Link and any sub-class of Link.
GetLinkFunction function = new GetLinkFunction<Link>(driver, Link.class));
```

So, I have the idea that since Link is parameterized, this where my problem is coming from. How do I fix that? I don't know what type parameter to declare for Link other than itself, but this also causes problems:

```
GetLinkFunction function = new GetLinkFunction<Link<Link>>(driver, Link.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the *raw* type of `Link` as your generic bound.

Change:

```
public class GetLinkFunction<L extends Link> implements Function<WebElement,L> {
```

To this (assuming you need the type of Link to also be a Link):

```
public class GetLinkFunction<L extends Link<? extends Link & LoadableComponent>> implements Function<WebElement, L> {
```

Comment: Link needs the generic parameter to pass through to LoadableComponent for classes which sub-class Link. IE: `SomeOtherLink extends Link<SomeOtherLink>`. However, Link is also mean to be used as it is, and in that case, do I just declare it as Link<Link>? Because in that case, the generic type parameter should refer to itself?